# How do I alphabetize cells in the same row but different columns, without changing the rest of the row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel document that involves a column that asks for 3 countries in three columns: Country1, Country2, and Country3. However, the countries in these columns are not alphabetized. How do I alphabetize the these three columns, on a row by row basis? For example, I would want to turn this (Please ignore the periods, I'm awful at formatting on this site and that's the only way I could get the lines to vaguely line up):

```
CaseNumber |  Country1 | Country2 | Country3
1          | Australia |  Zambia  |   USA
2          |    UK     |  Bahamas |  Russia
```

---

Into This:

```
CaseNumber |  Country1 | Country2 | Country3
1          | Australia |  USA     |   Zambia
2          |   Bahamas |  Russia  |  UK
```

Comment: Not very clearly about how do you sort these countries for 3 columns? I didn't find the relationship among 3 columns with countries...

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

1. Select the row, click on Sort & Filter, then Custom Sort.
2. Select Options, then choose Sort left to right
3. Select the Row, and click OK.

- Pros: No need for formula.
- Cons: You will need to do it on a row by row basis.

**Method 2**

Assuming the countries are in column B to D of Sheet1, enter the following formula on another sheet on cells not occupied by your data:

```
=SORT(B2:D2,3,1)
```

- Pros: Formula sort quickly for you
- Cons: The results are not on the same cells than the initials data